# How to add a scoring profile to an Azure Search index for specific string

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I know that you can boosts items that contain the defined field in the search term. But I would like to boost items that contain a specific string such as "£" in a  description field.

I imagine a scheme similar to this one:

```
"scoringProfiles": [  
    {  
      "name": "currency",  
      "text": {  
        "weights": {  
          "description": {
             "£" : 1.5 
          }
        }  
      }  
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture#stage-4-scoring) article to tune relevance scores in Azure Search. You can choose scoring profiles or term boosting.

More info about term boostring: [Lucene syntax query examples for building advanced queries in Azure Search > Example 5: Term boosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-lucene-examples#example-5-term-boosting)

Comment: I eventually used tags which support strings